# How improve add items under the List, when i have more than 2 elements

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework

The next code is functional, but I want know if exist a better way to do this function.

With linq I get a list with 4 elements, but I needed add those elements in a list of ProposalItems, the next code is the type of the list

```
private class ProposalItems
{
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }
}
```

And the next code is the method:

```
internal List<ProposalItems> GetProposalItems(int tradeId, int contendantId)
    {
        using (var db = new Entities())
        {
            //declare the list
            List<ProposalItems> items = new List<ProposalItems>();
            //query in linq
            var data = db.ES_SC_PropuestasPrecios
                .Join(db.ES_SC_CatalogoConceptos,
                prices => prices.renglon,
                concept => concept.renglon,
                (prices, concept) => new { ES_SC_PropuestasPrecios = prices, ES_SC_CatalogoConceptos = concept })
            .Where(w => w.ES_SC_CatalogoConceptos.idconcurso == tradeId && w.ES_SC_PropuestasPrecios.idconcursante == contendantId)
            //select the items
            .Select(s => new
            {
                Row = s.ES_SC_CatalogoConceptos.renglon,
                Quantity = s.ES_SC_CatalogoConceptos.cantidad,
                Price = s.ES_SC_PropuestasPrecios.preciounitario,
                Total = s.ES_SC_PropuestasPrecios.importe
            }).ToList();
            // loop to add the item in the list
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                items.Add(new ProposalItems { Row = (int)item.Row, Price = (double)item.Price, Quantity = (double)item.Quantity, Total = (double)item.Total });
            }
            return items;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to substitute your current select for this

```
.Select(s => new ProposalItems { 
    Row = (int)s.ES_SC_CatalogoConceptos.renglon,, 
    Price = (double)s.ES_SC_PropuestasPrecios.preciounitario, 
    Quantity = (double)s.ES_SC_CatalogoConceptos.cantidad, 
    Total = (double)s.ES_SC_PropuestasPrecios.importe 
}).ToList();
```